# inserting values at an index position in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'Area': ['Tipperary', 'Tipperary', 'Cork', 'Dublin'],
                     'Deaths': [11, 33, 44, 55],
                      'Year': [2007, 2007, 2007, 2008]}
)
```

is it possible to insert a value at an index position, say to replace 44 in the deaths column? would `test.iloc[2:1] = 22` work here? I am having issues using append to do this and was hopeful i could set variables in containers like `val = 22` and use to insert.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use `iloc`, try this:

```
test['Deaths'].iloc[2] = 22
```

Comment: magic, thank you @DNy